# Error messages when using OpenGL ES template

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, ios4

I made a new OpenGL ES application, and without modifying anything, I ran the program. It runs, but I see these error messages:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
open$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm12MemoryBuffer7getFileEPKcPSsx in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
fstat$INODE64 called from function _ZN4llvm12MemoryBuffer7getFileEPKcPSsx in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
mmap$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm3sys4Path14MapInFilePagesEiy in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
close$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm12MemoryBuffer7getFileEPKcPSsx in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
pthread_mutexattr_destroy$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm3sys5MutexC2Eb in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
```

The program displays a colored box that moves up and down. Is this what it's supposed to do? What do these error messages mean?

Comment: What version of the SDK / Xcode are you building this on?  Is this on the device or Simulator?

Comment: Using Xcode 3.2.4 with the simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been noticing the same. I'm running iOS sdk 4.1. But it only happens on the simulator.

From what I found at the apple forums, it seems to be a simulator bug. An Apple representative claimed that it was a bug on "their" end.

Here's the quote "This is a bug on our end, but as long as things are otherwise working for you, the logging can safely be ignored."

Comment: I removed it. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I then tried to run my code on my device (iphone 4.1) and even though the application opened up nothing was drawn to the screen. By they way, are you by any chance doing the tutorial from Chapter 1 of O'Reilly's iphone 3D programming book?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. How did you guess!?

Comment: Really? Apple said that its not their side? Then how do they explain that the same error occurs when running their OpenGL template?