# OpenGL ES Tutorial - "symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone"

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I will be very impressed if we manage to solve this.

I'm a beginner programmer following the first chapter tutorial in the O'Reilly book "iphone 3D programming". After trying to run the initial practice program I get the following error:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
open$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm12MemoryBuffer7getFileEPKcPSsx in image libLLVMContainer.dylib.
```

I've narrowed it down to this section of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];

m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];

[m_window addSubview: m_view];
[m_window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

where when I comment out the following line it works fine i.e. it launches, but doesn't draw the screen that is intended:

```
m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
```

Any idea of how I can debug this properly?

I appreciate all help offered :)

---

EDIT 1

I've found [this conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891504/error-messages-when-using-opengl-es-template) which says that it is a bug with the simulator. I then tried running my code on my device (iphone 4.1) and although there was no error message, I'm still not seeing anything drawn to the screen :)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to safely ignore these, because they just appear to be a bug in the way the iOS 4.1 interacts with the Simulator.  These console errors in the Simulator do not affect actual OpenGL ES rendering in my experience.

Your rendering issues are most likely elsewhere.